# Claims based authentication to log on to a device

Tags: authentication, operating-systems, sso, saml

Are there operating systems that allow logging on to the device (laptop, tablet etc.) using claims based authentication?

Comment: Well, Windows supports claims in kerberos tokens, but I guess what you're more referring to is federated authenticated via something like SAML/OAuth, etc?

Comment: yes please, SAML or OAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find anything substantial. Windows 10 supports auth via Azure AD which supports a federated IdP via WS-Trust.

Chrome OS supports google accounts, which can be backed by a SAML IdP.

In either case they have special implementations that rely on username/password combinations.

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 not only supports that but almost forces you to use either a Microsoft or School/Work account to log in. AFAIK, both use claims-based logins. You actually log in to a page on a Microsoft domain - you can sometimes see that happening when it reauthenticates you.